# running ipv6 at home network

Tags: ipv6

I'm looking for a home router solution that is able to do:

- DHCPv6
- NAT64 or something similar

my goal is to extend, my v6 test network (3 hosts), to my all local devices (tablets, xbox360, desktops, mobile, etc, printer, etc) but I want to still be able to to access the v4 world.

Please I'm not looking for a custom solution using an extra box as gateway. What I do accept is customized firmware to run in home routers (i.e: openwrt)

Comment: As interested as I am in an answer to this question it is really off topic here.

Comment: i just don't understand what is a "home network" other than a Network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### DD-WRT

**Tutorial on Getting IPv6 working**

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/IPv6

**Supported Devices**

http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Supported_Devices